# On Clojure, what is the difference of deftype and defrecord and why are they necessary beyound maps?

Tags: dictionary, clojure, hashmap, deftype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why Clojure has 5 ways to define a class instead of just one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142495/why-clojure-has-5-ways-to-define-a-class-instead-of-just-one)

What are their differences and why are they necessary when there is already map?

Comment: Not a duplicate since covers quite different themes from the linked question, voted to re-open

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed not exactly a duplicate but I managed to find my answer on the other thread that I somehow missed when searching. This is a great image: http://chasemerick.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/choosingtypeforms2.png?w=640